# Lack of Options in Gdal Tool "Build Overviews" QGis

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, satellite, resampling

I am using QGis 1.8 and I want to build overviews (pyramids) for satellite imagery using the Gdal Tool. I would like to use the resampling method "cubic convolution", but the option doesn't exist although it is listed in the online help (http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html). Two other options are in my list that don't show up in the online help however: "nearest" and "mode".

Does anybody know why "cubic" isn't there or can recommend me one of the other methods for use with satellite imagery?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Elena

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cubic mode is incorporated in QGIS Master. Looks like noone had thought of adding it to the dropdownbox earlier.

You can use gisinternals' GDAL standalone version to do all things that current QGIS Lisboa does not offer yet.

Or simply try to insert `-r cubic` in the command box of QGIS.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I will have to start finding out about things like "gisinternals" and "command box"... :)

Comment: QGIS writes the commands for GDAL in a box underneath the input mask. You can edit that command, if you do not like the presets. The syntax is described on the GDAL help pages.